# Namespace in rails routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails

First, why do we need to namespace controllers?

The example on [rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing) shows

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :post, :comments
end
```

In this case, we have paths such as GET /admin/posts. Is it identical to GET /posts? Or is GET /posts kept as original while another GET /admin/posts is added as extra?

Does rails create any other stuff for namespace?

Answer (score 1):

You dont have to use namespaces if you dont want to, but it's there to make your life easier, specially in big applications with a lot of controllers. And no, routes arent duplicated if you namespace them, unless you specify the route again in your route file without the namespace, but that doesnt make much sense.

Comment: Then why does rails guides say "If you want to route /posts to Admin::PostsController" and "If you want to route /admin/posts to PostsController"? Why there are Admin::PostsController and PostsController at the same time if they are identical?